# How use a custom component for the header in material-react-table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using table from `'material-react-table'`.

I have created columns in which some column heading have tooltip
like this:

```
const col = [
{
    accessorKey: 'parent',
    header: 'Group Name',
    minSize: 170,
    maxSize: 500,
    size: 170,
    Cell: ({ cell }) => <Typography noWrap>{cell.getValue()}</Typography>,
  },
 {
    accessorKey: 'ms',
    header: <ToolTip title="MS" tooltiptext="Management Score" />,
    minSize: 70,
    maxSize: 70,
    size: 70,
  },
]
```

Everything is working but only issue is it is not able to read its header.

For the column heading which doesn't have any tooltip, it's showing the correct header name on click of action (3 dots), but showing [object Object] for tooltip header

This is without tooltip:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ou7HJ.png)

This is with tooltip:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6fJP.png)

I want it to show like - sort by RS ascending, not sort by [object Object] ascending